# Java 8 Streams multiple grouping By

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a temperature record something like this

```
dt        |AverageTemperature |AverageTemperatureUncertainty|City   |Country |Latitude|Longitude
----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-------+--------+--------+---------
1963-01-01|-5.417000000000002 |0.5                          |Karachi|Pakistan|57.05N  |10.33E  
1963-02-01|-4.7650000000000015|0.328                        |Karachi|Pakistan|57.05N  |10.33E  
1964-01-01|-5.417000000000002 |0.5                          |Karachi|Pakistan|57.05N  |10.33E  
1964-02-01|-4.7650000000000015|0.328                        |Karachi|Pakistan|57.05N  |10.33E  
1965-01-01|11.417000000000002 |0.5                          |Karachi|Pakistan|57.05N  |10.33E 
1965-02-01|12.7650000000000015|0.328                        |Karachi|Pakistan|57.05N  |10.33E
```

I have to parse this into a POJO and calculate the average delta as per the following problem statement:

> Use the Streams API to calculate the average annual temperature delta
>   for each country. To calculate delta the average temperature in 1900
>   would be subtracted from the average temperature in 1901 to obtain the
>   delta from 1900 to 1901 for a particular city. The average of all
>   these deltas is the average annual temperature delta for a city. The
>   average of all cities in a country is the average of a country.

My Temperate POJO looks like following having getters and setters

```
public class Temperature {
    private java.util.Date date;
    private double averageTemperature;
    private double averageTemperatureUncertainty;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
}
```

I have maintained a list of temperatures as this problem is to be achieved using streams.

To calculate the delta I am trying to use the following streams but I am still unable to calculate the actual delta, as I have to calculate the average country delta, I have performed grouping over country, city and date.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<Integer, Double>>> countriesMap = this.getTemperatures().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Temperature::getDate))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Temperature::getCountry,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Temperature::getCity,
                        Collectors.groupingBy
                                (t -> {
                                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                                            calendar.setTime(t.getDate());
                                            return calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                        }, 
                        Collectors.averagingDouble(Temperature::getAverageTemperature)))));
```

In order to calculate the delta we will have to calculate the differences 
for the `Map<Integer, Double>`.

For calculating the difference I came up with the following code but couldn't connect following code with the above one

```
Stream.of(10d, 20d, 10d) //this is sample data that I that I get in `Map<Integer, Double>` of countriesMap
        .map(new Function<Double, Optional<Double>>() {
            Optional<Double> previousValue = Optional.empty();
            @Override
            public Optional<Double> apply(Double current) {
                Optional<Double> value = previousValue.map(previous -> current - previous);
                previousValue = Optional.of(current);
                return value;
            }
        })
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

How can I calculate the delta using streams in one go or how to perform stream operations over `countriesMap` in order to calculate delta and acheive the mentioned problem statment.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To cut down the problem statement into a smaller block, another approach that you could look into is parsing through the `year`ly temperature and computing the delta for them, further `average`ing it. This would though have to be done for all the values of type `Map<Integer, Double>` within the inner `Map` in your question. It would look something like:

```
Map<Integer, Double> unitOfWork = new HashMap<>(); // innermost map you've attained ('yearToAverageTemperature' map)
unitOfWork = unitOfWork.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
// the values sorted based on the year from a sorted map
List<Double> srtedValPerYear = new ArrayList<>(unitOfWork.values());
// average of deltas from the complete list 
double avg = IntStream.range(0, srtedVal.size() - 1)
        .mapToDouble(i -> (srtedVal.get(i + 1) - srtedVal.get(i)))
        .average().orElse(Double.NaN);
```

To note further, this is just an average of one `City`'s record of `<Year, AverageTemperature>`, you would have to iterate through all your `City` keyset and similarly for all your `Country` keyset to exhaustively find out such averages.

Further moving this unit of work into a method, iterating through the complete map of maps, this might be accomplished as :

```
// The average of all cities in a country is the average of a country.
AtomicReference<Double> countryValAvg = new AtomicReference<>(0.0);
countriesMap.forEach((country, cityMap) -> {
    // The average of all these deltas is the average annual temperature delta for a city.
    AtomicReference<Double> cityAvgTemp = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);
    cityMap.forEach((city, yearMap) -> cityAvgTemp.set(cityAvgTemp.get() + averagePerCity(yearMap)));
    double avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity = cityAvgTemp.get() / cityMap.size();

    countryValAvg.set(countryValAvg.get() + avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity);
});
System.out.println(countryValAvg.get() / countriesMap.size());
```

where `averagePerCity` is the method that does following

```
double averagePerCity(Map<Integer, Double> unitOfWork) {
    unitOfWork = unitOfWork.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    List<Double> srtedVal = new ArrayList<>(unitOfWork.values());
    return IntStream.range(0, srtedVal.size() - 1)
            .mapToDouble(i -> (srtedVal.get(i + 1) - srtedVal.get(i)))
            .average().orElse(Double.NaN);
}
```

***Note***: The code above might be missing validations, its just to provide an idea of how could the complete problem be broken into smaller parts and then solved.

***Edit1***: Which [could be improved further as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132104/java-8-streams-multiple-grouping-by/54132424?noredirect=1#comment95116334_54132424) :

```
// The average of all cities in a country is the average of a country.
AtomicReference<Double> countryValAvg = new AtomicReference<>(0.0);
countriesMap.forEach((country, cityMap) -> {
    // The average of all these deltas is the average annual temperature delta for a city.
    double avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity = cityMap.values()
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(Quick::averagePerCity) // Quick is my class name
            .average()
            .orElse(Double.NaN);
    countryValAvg.set(countryValAvg.get() + avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity);
});
System.out.println(countryValAvg.get() / countriesMap.size());
```

***Edit2***: And further to

```
double avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity = countriesMap.values().stream()
        .mapToDouble(cityMap -> cityMap.values()
                .stream()
                .mapToDouble(Quick::averagePerCity) // Quick is my class name
                .average()
                .orElse(Double.NaN))
        .average().orElse(Double.NaN);
```

Comment: Instead of `AtomicReference<Double> cityAvgTemp = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);
    cityMap.forEach((city, yearMap) -> cityAvgTemp.set(cityAvgTemp.get() + averagePerCity(yearMap)));
    double avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity = cityAvgTemp.get() / cityMap.size();`, you may simply use `double avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity = cityMap.values().stream().mapToDouble(this::averagePerCity).average();`

Comment: @Holger `double avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity = cityAvgTemp.get() / cityMap.size();`

Isn't this avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCountry.?

Comment: @HammadNaeem no, the per country temperature delta is evaluated outside of that iteration.

Comment: You can repeat the simplification for the outer map too; instead of `AtomicReference<Double> countryValAvg = new AtomicReference<>(0.0);
countriesMap.forEach((country, cityMap) -> { /* code not using country */ countryValAvg.set(countryValAvg.get() + avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity); }) double result = countryValAvg.get() / countriesMap.size();`, you can simply use `double result = countriesMap.values().stream().mapToDouble(cityMap -> /* expression used to initialize avgAnnualTempDeltaPerCity */).average();`